# How do I query a sheet by two cell variables?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have one sheet with entries from a google form and one where it would display a filtered version based on two inputs from the user. I would like to query the sheet and display specific columns based on if the two entered cell values both match a value in their respective columns.

I have this
`=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!A2:R,"Select L,M,N,O,P where C = " &D3)`

I know the syntax can be picky but I cant add `"and K = " &G3)` to the above working function as it throws back and error of "Formula parse error". I know there is a row that matches the entered values i have so i am not sure why it isn't displaying. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

In google sheets, you concatenate string with &, so your correct code is

`=QUERY('Form Responses 1'!A2:R,"Select L,M,N,O,P where C = " & D3 & " and K = " & G3 )`

I prefer using the FILTER function:
FILTER(range, condition1, [condition2, ...])

`=FILTER('Form Responses 1'!L2:P,'Form Responses 1'!C2:C = D3,'Form Responses 1'!K2:K = G3)`

FILTER function reference: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en